# using a variable in :contains - how to

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using accordion menu on an e-commerce site. The menu stays open with the options until the product page. On that page I am trying to use the breadcrumbs to match text in the menu and then apply a class to open the menu to the correct category for the page.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var bctext = $('#ProductBreadcrumb ul li:last-child').prev('li').children().text();
$('ul#accordion a:contains(bctext)').parent().parent().addClass('special');

 });
```

The variable returns the correct text, and if I put a matching string ("Tomato Sauces") in the `:contains` it works just like I want it to and applies the class.  However when I use bctext variable it wont work.

I also tried `a:contains($(bctext))` and it didn't work.  Is it my syntax?

Thanks

Comment: Just a quick one, to make your code more readable, select the code and hit Code sample in the editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('ul#accordion a:contains(' + bctext + ')')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Traversing/contains](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/contains) also:

```
$('ul#accordion a').contains(bctext);
```

Comment: I like this way best, I always avoid string concatenations within a query if I can. It's more secure, clear, and just seems cleaner

Comment: `$.fn.contains()` was deprecated in 1.2 and replaced with the filter expression in 1.3. See http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2#Removed_Functionality

Comment: @cobbal - I'm curious, what's more secure with this method compared to selector string concatenation?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$('ul#accordion a:contains(bctext)').parent().parent().addClass('special');
```

to:

```
$('ul#accordion a:contains(' + bctext + ')').parent().parent().addClass('special');
```

The first way, the way you had it, is telling JavaScript to use the string 'bctext' as the contains parameter.  What you actually want is the string which is contained within the bctext variable.  Therefore you have to use it outside of the quotes and use concatenation to create your selector string.

Comment: thanks, i was confused because i thought if it wasnt in quotes it would know it was a variable...still learning...

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul#accordion a').filter(':contains(' + bctext + ')'
```

is now preferred to the [deprecated](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2#Removed_Functionality)

```
$('ul#accordion a').contains(bctext);
```

(as commented by Crescent Fresh)

Answer (score 0):

This line should be:

```
$('ul#accordion a:contains(' + bctext + ')').parent().parent().addClass('special');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a **special-character-save** version, that uses **filter** instead of the deprecated **contains** method.

`$('ul#accordion a').filter(function () { return $(this).text() == bctext; })`