# jQuery Pass parameter to filter statement with contains clause

Tags: jquery, filter

In the method below I can search divs with a class of bar for the text foo and underline the text contained within:

```
function UnderlineText() {
    $(".bar").filter(":contains(foo)").css("text-decoration", "underline");
}
```

But I would like to pass a parameter to the method instead containing the string foo.

I have tried various permutations as seen in a previous question about the deprecated [`.contains`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274710/using-a-variable-in-contains-how-to)

but I can't get it to work.

What is the best way to achieve this?

```
function UnderlineText(searchText) {
    $(".bar").filter(":contains(*searchText*)").css("text-decoration", "underline");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function UnderlineText(searchText) {
    $(".bar").filter(":contains("+searchText+")").css("text-decoration", "underline");
}
```

would solve the problem.

Comment: Yes this works great, thanks. It must have been my combination of single and double quotes that was preventing it from working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you manage to get the selector working, you will select the whole containing element (p, span, div, etc.), so using a simple `css()` call will end up underlining the whole block of text. To underline the specific part, you'll have to use something like:

```
function underline(query) {
  $('.bar').filter(':contains("' + query+ '")').each(function() {
    var html = $(this).html();
    html = html.replace(query, '<span style="text-decoration: underline">' + query + '</span>';
    $(this).html(html);
  });
}
```

This is still not that good, since it might replace the query while it's in an attribute or somesuch, but it's a step towards getting stuff underlined separately.

Comment: Well, I certainly think this is very good. Perhaps there is a more elegant solution but underlining just the searched for text is an excellent idea.